# Is "config tuning" on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Is it suiteable to ask questions that involve the configuration of the database with all it's parameters? I'm not talking about optimizing queries, requests,.. but the settings that are provided by the database to alter how things work on the inside.

Are such question ok on dba or should they move to serverfault?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think these questions are ok on DBA so long as they are accompanied with a detailed technical explanation of what the settings are intended for.

Comment: @JeffAtwoord I couldn't agree more. I remember answering a question about date expression tagged as MySQL only to find out the person asking was referring to Oracle. So accurate details are always most appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely - this is a significant part of bread-and-butter DBA work.